# Strange resource handling Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio, resources

I have a very strange problem with resources in a C++ dll in Visual Studio 2008. With Visual Studio 2005 it works without problems.

My resources are a number of scripts and hex files that are referred to in `CompactFlxisDownload.rc2`.

The resources are used via `FindResource`, `LoadResource` and `LockResource`.

The problem is that the resources are not correctly separated in Visual Studio 2008. E.g. when resource 3 is used, all resources from 3 till the last resource are seen as one resource, the resources seems not to be separated correctly.

If I look at the resource part in the dll, in Visual Studio 2005 the resources are separated by a sequence of 0. In visual Studio 2008 the resources are separated by 'P', 'PA' or 'PAD', depending on the length of the resource ('P', 'PA', 'PAD' seems to be added to make it a multiple of 4).

Anyone any idea what the cause is of this strange behavior?

Comment: Sure, "PAD" is the filler used to align the resources.  Surely your real problem is that the strings are not zero-terminated so you can't properly find the end of the text.  You probably relied on this working by accident, one that fails when no padding is required.  If you can't get the 0 into the original file then using SizeOfResource() is required.

Comment: @Hans: I assumed also that PAD was used for alignment, but: 1. PAD is not there when VS2005 is used, 2. it works fine with VS2005, 3. some of the resource are hex files for which null termination is not applicable. Therefor it is still unclear why it works in VS2005 and not in VS2008

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by using SizeOfResource. The still open issue is the difference between Windows XP VS2005 and Windows 7 VS2008.

Used code:

```
hScript = LoadResource(hInstance, hRes);
CString Script = (LPCTSTR) LockResource(hScript);
DWORD size1 = SizeOfResource((hInstance, hRes);
DWORD size2 = Script.GetLength();
```

Result:

VS2005: size1 = 449, size2 = 449

VS2008: size1 = 449, size2 = 5520

Any suggestion why I get this different results?